# VMware Tools skipping X drivers

Tags: installation, vmware, xorg

[re-posting from the "Not Answered" thread, https://communities.vmware.com/thread/416544]

When trying to build VMware Tools, I get the following message:

```
Detected X server version 1.11.4
Distribution provided drivers for Xorg X server are used.
Skipping X configuration because X drivers are not included.
```

I then removed `xserver-xorg-video-vmware`, restarted the VM and tried running the install script again, only to receive the same message.

I then installed `xserver-xorg-video-vmmouse` and `libgl1-mesa-dri` after searching, but again, only to receive the same message.